# Design Pattern to model Request and Response Objects for Webservices

Tags: java, web-services, rest, design-patterns, jax-rs

I have about 7 REST web services to implement. Some of these web services have a standard (identical) response, while some have different responses.

The requests for these web services are different but some requests and some of the responses have the same underlying data objects.

I am not sure if I have to build separate request/response classes for each web service or reuse a standard one. I would like to know if there is a design pattern to model the request objects and response objects for these web services.

Ok, say Account and Book are two rest resources my web services will be working on.

```
class Account {
    String username;
    String id;
}


class Book {
    String title;
    String isbn;
}
```

So my web services look like this:

```
MYAPI/CreateAccountandBook
MYAPI/Account/Create
MYAPI/Book/Create
MYAPI/Book/Update/{isbn}
MYAPI/Account/Update/{id}
MYAPI/Account/getInfo/{id}
```

and so on.

Now `CreateAccountandBook` request will take an account object and a list of books in the payload.
Also the response object for `MYAPI/Account/getInfo/{id}` has an account object and a list of books associated with that account. But the response object also includes a `statusCode` and `Description`.

Now I would like to create classes for these request and response objects
in the best possible way.

Okay for a start.

I have two abstract classes `StandardRequest` and `StandardResponse`.

All requests classes will extend the Standard Request class and customize accordingly. 
All response classes will extend the Standard response class and customize accordingly.

But these requests and response can be way different from each other but still re-use the same entity objects.

For instance:

`createAccountandBook` request object looks like this:

```
class CreateAccountAndBookRequest {
   Account account;
   List<Book> books;
}
```

while the response for the `getInfo` web service  is:

```
class GetInfoResponse {
   Account account;
   List<Book> books;
   String statusCode;
   String description;
}
```

so there is overlap across request and response classes. I can create two (req/res) classes for each web service. But would like to know if there is a better way to model these classes.

Comment: You want a design pattern that designs objects for you....?

Comment: Not exactly! I want to know the best way to structure these request and response classes

Comment: I don't think there is any possible answer to your question. You provide no information about the properties or behaviors of these objects you are trying to design, so there is no way to help you. You should make an attempt at it and if you run into problems come back with more specific questions.

Comment: updated with more info..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had a similar dilemma; I went in the **generic** direction and am liking the results; haven't looked back since.

If I had a `GetAccounts` API method the signature might look like.

```
public final Response<Account[]> getAccounts()
```

Naturally the same principle may be applied to requests.

```
public final Response<Account[]> rebalanceAccounts(Request<Account[]>) { ... }
```

In my opinion; decoupling the individual entities from requests and responses yields a neater domain and object graph.

Below is an example of what such a generic response object might look like. In my case; I'd built the server to have a generic response for all requests to enhance error handling and lower coupling between domain objects and response objects.

```
public class Response<T> {

  private static final String R_MSG_EMPTY = "";
  private static final String R_CODE_OK = "OK";

  private final String responseCode;
  private final Date execDt;
  private final String message;

  private T response;

  /**
   * A Creates a new instance of Response
   *
   * @param code
   * @param message
   * @param execDt
   */
  public Response(final String code, final String message, final Date execDt) {

    this.execDt = execDt == null ? Calendar.getInstance().getTime() : execDt;
    this.message = message == null ? Response.R_MSG_EMPTY : message;
    this.responseCode = code == null ? Response.R_CODE_OK : code;
    this.response = null;
  }

  /**
   * @return the execDt
   */
  public Date getExecDt() {

    return this.execDt;
  }

  /**
   * @return the message
   */
  public String getMessage() {

    return this.message;
  }

  /**
   * @return the response
   */
  public T getResponse() {

    return this.response;
  }

  /**
   * @return the responseCode
   */
  public String getResponseCode() {

    return this.responseCode;
  }

  /**
   * sets the response object
   *
   * @param obj
   * @return
   */
  public Response<T> setResponse(final T obj) {

    this.response = obj;
    return this;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is well and good for the response, but the trick seems to be how the request and response are linked, especially considering that they will be different types

Comment: You say " lower coupling between domain objects and response objects". that's a nice goal but imho your response Response<Account> is very tightly coupled to the model object Account. Any change to Account immediately affects the response streamed to the user. If you have an API that publishes what the response contains, a change in the model object Account would break your API and your customers would not like that.

Comment: As @inor said, this answer violates the Single Responsibility and Common Closure principles. Maybe a better way to put it is in the words of Uncle Bob's Clean Architecture. Quoting from the book:

"You might be tempted to have these data structures contain references to Entity objects. [...] This makes sense because [they] share so much data. Avoid this temptation! Over time they will change for different reasons, so tying them together violates the Common Closure and Single Responsibility Principles. The result would be lots of tramp data and lots of conditionals in your code."

Answer (score 69):

The big problem I see in all the answers so far including the question is that they all violate the principal of separation of concerns, information hiding and encapsulation. In all answers request (and response) classes are tightly coupled to model classes. That is a more serious issue and raises a question more important than the relationship between the requests and responses...

**What should be the relationship between the request/response classes and the model classes?**

Since the request class (e.g. CreateBookRequest) and the model class Book have mostly the same data properties, you could do any of the following:

A. Put all your data/getters/setters into the Book class and have the CreateBookRequest extend from the class

B. Have your CreateBookRequest contain a Book as a member (as in the question and answers given by ekostadinov, Juan Henao, . The generic usage given by dasm80x86 is also a special case of this)

C. Put data/getters/setters in BookBase and have both Book and CreateBookRequest extend from BookBase

D. Put all/some data/getters/setters in BookStuff and have both Book and CreateBookRequest contain a BookStuff

E. Put all the data/getters/setters in both Book and CreateBookRequest. (you can copy-paste).

**The correct answer is E.**  We are all so trained and eager to "re-use" that this is the least intuitive answer.

The request class CreateBookRequest (as well as the response class CreateBookResponse) and the model class Book, should NOT be be in same class hierarchy (other than both having Object as a top most parent) (A,C). Also the CreateBookRequest should not refer/contain to the model Book or to any of the composite classes that are members in the Book class (B,D)

**The reasons for this are as follows:**

1. You want to modify the model object or the request object independent of each other. If your request refers to your model (as in A-D) any change in the model will be reflected in the interface, and therefore break your API. Your customers are going to write clients according to the API dictated by your request/response classes and they don't want to change those clients whenever you make a change to your model classes. you want the request/response and the model to vary independently.
2. Separation of concerns. Your request class CreateBookRequest may contain all kinds of interface/protocol related annotations and members (e.g. validation annotations that the JAX-RS implementation knows how to enforce). These interface-related annotations should not be in the model object. (as in A)
3. from an OO perspective CreateBookRequest is not a Book (not IS_A) nor does it contain a book.

**The flow of control should be as follows:**

1. The interface/control layer (the one that receives the Rest-API calls) should use as its methods parameters Request/Response classes defined specifically for that layer (e.g. CreateBookRequest). Let the container/infrastructure create those from the REST/HTTP/whatever request.
2. The methods in the interface/control layer should create in some way an instance of a model class object, and copy values from the request classes
   into the model class object,
3. The methods in the interface/control layer should call a BO/Manager/Whatever (in the model layer... which is responsible for business logic) passing to it the model class object and not the interface class/method parameter class object (in other words, NOT as Luiggi Mendoza has shown in his answer)
4. The model/BO method would return some model class object or some "primitive".
5. Now the interface method (the caller) should create an interface class response object, and copy values into it from the model class object returned by the model/BO. (Just like Luiggi Mendoza as shown in his answer)
6. The container/infrastructure would then create the JSON/XML/whatever response from the response class object.

**Now to the question asked... What should be the relationship between the requests and response classes?**

Request classes should extend from request classes and not extend nor contain  response classes, and vice versa. (as was also suggested by question asker).
Usually you have a very basic BaseRequest class, extended by something like CreateRequest, UpdateRequest, etc... where properties common to all create requests are in CreateRequest which is then extended by more specific request classes such as CreateBookRequest...
Similarly, but parallel to it, the is the Response class hierarchy.

The question asker also asked whether it's ok for both CreateBookRequest and CreateBookResponse to contain the same member such as (Never a model class though!) BookStuffInRequestAndResponse which properties common to both the request and response?

This is not as severe an issue as having the request or response refer to a class that is also referred to by the model. The problem with this is that if you need to make a change to your API request and make it in BookStuffInRequestAndResponse, it immediately affects your response (and vice versa).

It's not so bad because 1) if your customer needs to fix their client code because you change the request parameters, they may as well fix handle/fix the changed response and 2) most likely changes in the request would require change to the response any way (for example adding a new attribute), however, that may not always be the case.

Comment: Hi inor, super nice and practical explanation, thanks a lot. About the "flow of control", point  2) The methods in the The interface/control layer should create in some way an instance of a model class object, and copy values from the request classes into the model class object.   It is ok to leave the interface/control as light as possible and  have the logic to "transform" the request model to t he data domain model in the BO class? Or it is preferable (not it's responsability) to have the BO class only working on a clean data model?

Comment: Hi Alex 75, the BO should definitely not be dealing with request objects, only with BO/Model objects. The creation of the BO request objects could be done by some factory method called by the interface/control layer class. Similarly mapping from BO/model objects to response objects. Consider using Dozr as the mapping factory http://dozer.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @inor What does "BO" mean or refer to in this answer?

Comment: @IbrahimShendy BO = Business Object.

Comment: @inor gr8 explanation. I've designed lots of REST AP with the same pattern (The same way you explain :-) ). We had BaseRequest/BaseResponse extended by respective REST requests and responses which contains  DO = Data Objects and a Transformation service Transfer all the object to BO= Business Objects and then controller pass them to corresponding services/providers.  After performing business logic again transform service transfer BO to DO and then the controller returns the REST API responses back to the caller.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if there is such design pattern. I do the following:

- For GET requests, define the parameters in query string or in path. Preferred way is path. Also, you will have few parameters for your service. Each service will handle this on its own. There is no reusability here.
- For POST requests, consume the parameters in JSON format that comes in the body of the request. Also, use an adapter (depending on the technology you're using) that will map the JSON content to a specific class that you receive as parameter.
- For responses, there are two approaches:

  - You can create a custom `ResponseWrapper` class that will be your real response. This will contain the response code, the description and a field called value which stores the real content of the response in case of a success processing of the input data. The class will look like this:

    ```
    public class ResponseWrapper {
        private int statusCode;
        private String description;
        private String value;
    }
    ```

    In this case, `String value` will store the concrete response in JSON format. For example:

    ```
    @Path("/yourapi/book")
    public class BookRestfulService {

        @POST("/create")
        @Produces("json")
        public ResponseWrapper createBook(Book book) {
            ResponseWrapper rw = new ResponseWrapper();
            //do the processing...
            BookService bookService = new BookService();
            SomeClassToStoreResult result = bookService.create(book);
            //define the response...
            rw.setStatusCode(...);
            rw.setDescription("...");
            rw.setValue( convertToJson(result) );
        }

        static String convertToJson(Object object) {
            //method that probably will use a library like Jackson or Gson
            //to convert the object into a proper JSON strong
        }
    }
    ```
  - Reuse the [HTTP Response Status Code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html), use 200 (or 201, this depends on the type of request) for successful requests and a proper status code for the response. If your response has status code 200 (or 201) then return the proper object in JSON format. If your response has a different status code, provide a JSON object like this:

    ```
    { "error" : "There is no foo in bar." }
    ```

There is a trade off using RESTful services with JSON or XML, and that's the price of complexity for consumers, who may not know the structure of the response. In case of WS-* web services, the trade-off comes in performance terms (compared ton RESTful approach).

Comment: Thanks! actually I am using a Response builder as part of jax-rs to do the json/xml generation. I just pass a JAXB object to this builder and it reutrns a json/xml response. I am not sure the "value" field will work in this case?

Comment: Then probably you have nothing else to do. Just provide a good documentation of your services for the consumers to map the response with no problems.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try to implement something and will update the post!

Comment: @DntFrgtDSemiCln that's wrong to let jax-rs do the response generation FROM model object! because your response object and your model object should vary independently.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza that's a great example of how the response should be handled. You are right in that you de-coupled the response object from the model object. Jax-rs can generate the xml/json from your ResponseWrapper. It's wrong to return the model object like Luiggi suggested. But your handling of the request is wrong. The right way is to  decouple the request object from the model object Book. you need "public ResponseWrapper createBook(BookRequest bookRequest). Then your interfacing method should create the model object Book from the request object BookRequest and pass Book to the model.

Comment: @inor I’ve not stated that you should use model classes directly for request/response communication. This is just a sample. In real life, you have different classes for data transfer object and domain model, and a layer that helps you translate objects between these.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza 1) i think this is a "real life" question. The asker wants a real life answer. he already considered several "sample" alternatives 2) you gave a good "real life" handling of the response i'm just pointing out that you should have also handled the request part as "real life" solution. why do a "sample" for the request? 3) Everywhere i look i see "sample life" implementation (including actual production code of well known companies that i've worked at).

Answer (score 1):

About the

> if there is a Design Pattern to model the request objects and response objects

the standard way, you can consider is [Command design pattern](http://java.dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-command). Since it allows you to encapsulate a command request as an object. And thereby letting you parameterize clients with different requests, queue or log requests, responses and support undoable operations etc.

As sample implementation:

```
  abstract class Request{
    public abstract void Execute();
    public abstract void UnExecute();
  } 

   class AccountAndBookRequest extends Request{
   Account account;
   List<Book> books;
   }
```

Comment: UnExecute? What the heck does that mean?

Comment: Your business domain may allow Transaction rollback.

Comment: By using model objects (Account, Book) in your request (AccountAndBookRequest) you are tightly coupling model objects and request objects

Comment: Yes, this example may use a bit more abstraction and interfaces would be better, than concrete models. DI for example is a good candidate here. You are right @inor

Answer (score 0):

```
 public ResponseDto(){
     String username;
     int id;
     ArrayList books <Book> = new ArrayList<Book>();

    // proper getters and setters...
    @Override
    public String toString(){
       //parse this object to return a proper response to the rest service,
       //you can parse using some JSON library like GSON
    }
}
```

Comment: That's wrong because you are tightly coupling the response object ResponseDto to the model object Book. They need to be able to vary independently. in your answer any change to the model would affect the response

Comment: Generify the Response DTO

Answer (score -1):

you can try Hexagonal Architecture, it consist in put your business logic in the middle and access it via rest, soap, smtp, etc.

and in your Rest files you just need to expose the path and call a class with all the things you need to do like a DAO, or something else.

if the service refer to the same, you can leave in a single class, or separate depending of the propose of the services.

For your problem you can create a DTO (Data Transfer Object) with simple data that you need, like account number, books, description, and you can override the toString() to give a proper response or convert the data in a json reponse.

you can check http://alistair.cockburn.us/Hexagonal+architecture , i think is the best practice for that

Comment: Thanks for the answer!But I think its different from what  I am looking for.